# « Savoir ce que vous parlez » ou « savoir de quoi vous parlez » ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

> Je ne sais pas de quoi vous parlez.

I originally put *ce que*, and I was wondering if *ce que* could still be right? What is the difference between *ce que/ce qui* and *quoi*?

Comment: I don't think "ce que" because "on parle de qqch", and so at best it should be "ce dont". But I'm no expert...

Comment: _Je ne sais pas ce que vous parlez_ means that I didn't identify in which language you are talking.

Comment: FWIW, you wouldn't say the literal translation in English either: "I don't know what you *speak*." You would say "I don't know what you are *saying*". And in French you would say "Je ne sais pas ***ce que*** tu *racontes*." IOW, if you translate the verb correctly then things are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *ce que* in this sentence, it would be wrong:

> **Wrong:** Je ne sais pas *ce que* vous parlez.

Here are correct sentences with translations, I hope they help you to understand the difference:

> Je ne sais pas *ce dont* vous parlez. => I don't know what you are talking about.
>
> Je ne sais pas *de quoi* vous parlez. => I don't know what you are talking about.
>
> Je ne sais pas *de qui* vous parlez. => I don't know whom you are talking about.

First two sentences are correct but *ce dont* is more elegant (and would be used when written), and *de quoi* is more common in conversations.

*ce qui* or *ce quoi* cannot be used in your example.

Comment: "Ce qui/quoi" can't be used in these examples because with parler the object has to be introduced by "de", It is "parler de".

Comment: Correct, I was also thinking about *Je ne sais pas de ce quoi vous parlez*. I think it could be used but it isn't really appropriate.

Comment: Et je ne pense pas que ce soit correct.

Comment: En cherchant sur Google, il semble que *de ce quoi on parle* soit parfois utilisé. Mais j'avoue que je trouve que ça sonne bizarre aussi. Est-ce pour autant incorrect?

Comment: [comment moved to question]

Comment: "Je ne sais pas ce dont vous parlez." => seems awkward in my book. Might be grammatically correct, but in a conversation people will say "je ne sais pas de quoi vous parlez" 90% of the time (in France at least).

Comment: "Je ne sais pas ce que vous parlez." sounds correct to me but meaning "I don't know what language can speak". "- Je ne sais pas ce que vous parlez dans votre pays - On parle anglais.".

Comment: @guillaume31 `ce dont` is more elegant as stated and more posh, but still it's used a lot in literature